# Use Sed to find and replace json field

Tags: json, bash, unix, sed

I have set of json files where after last key value pair i have comma which needs to be replaced.

```
{
    "RepetitionTime": 0.72,
    "TaskName":"WM",
    "Manufacturer": "Siemens",
    "ManufacturerModelName": "Skyra",
    "MagneticFieldStrength": 3.0,
    "EchoTime":"0.033",
}
```

It should look like:

```
{
    "RepetitionTime": 0.72,
    "TaskName":"WM",
    "Manufacturer": "Siemens",
    "ManufacturerModelName": "Skyra",
    "MagneticFieldStrength": 3.0,
    "EchoTime": 0.033
}
```

How can i achive this using sed. 
Edit: Changed output - There should not be any "" around 0.033.

```
sed -i  \'7i'\\t'\"EchoTime\": \0.033\' sub-285345_task-WM_acq-RL_bold.json
```

is not helping me. I have tried few other options but no success..

I trioed using simplejson and json package in python too. But given that the files are incorrct json, json.loads(file) throws errors..

I would prefer sed over python for now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sed -Ei.bak 's/^([[:blank:]]*"EchoTime[^"]*":)"([^"]*)",$/\1\2/' file.json
```

will do it

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "RepetitionTime": 0.72,
    "TaskName":"WM",
    "Manufacturer": "Siemens",
    "ManufacturerModelName": "Skyra",
    "MagneticFieldStrength": 3.0,
    "EchoTime":0.033
}
```

---

**Notes**

- `E` to enable extended regular expressions.
- `i` to enable inplace editing, a backup file with .bak extension is created.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command.

```
sed -i 's#\(.*\)EchoTime":"\(.*\)",$#\1EchoTime":\2#' sub-285345_task-WM_acq-RL_bold.json
```

Comment: I have made a small edit to the output. how to tackle that change..?

Comment: The `.*` in the beginning is ill-advised. You check for blank spaces.

Comment: @mona_sax i just want keep the indent of json file.

Comment: Using blank spaces will not let you loose the indent in anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not limited to sed and open for awk , then following can be used :

```
awk ' BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}/EchoTime/ {gsub(/\"|\,/,"",$2)}1'  file.json
{
    "RepetitionTime": 0.72,
    "TaskName":"WM",
    "Manufacturer": "Siemens",
    "ManufacturerModelName": "Skyra",
    "MagneticFieldStrength": 3.0,
    "EchoTime":0.033
}
```

Explanation:

`FS=OFS=":"`  : This will set input and o/p field separator as ":"

`/EchoTime/` : Search for the line containing EchoTime.

`/EchoTime/{gsub(/\"|\,/,"",$2)}`: Once echo time is found use global sub to replace , double quotes and comma in second field of that line.

`1` : awk's default action is to print.

For making changes in original file:

```
awk ' BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}/EchoTime/ {gsub(/\"|\,/,"",$2)}1'  file.json >json.tmp && mv json.tmp file.json
```